# JavaScript passing the result from a function onto another (with promises)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, d3.js, async-await

Hi folks and happy Saturday!

Though *JavaScript* isn't my prime language, I've been learning quite a bit about asynchronous functions and I thought I had understood the whole thing. Well, obviously not!

I have this *csv* file that is currently on my GitHub repo. Let's call it *"csv_file"*. Its content looks like this:

```
Ind,Sentence
0,Hello world!
1,How are you?
2,Yeah all good thx
etc..
```

I'm using **d3**'s built-in *.csv()* method to fetch the file, and everything is working fine. I have this first function:

```
const fetchData = (data) => {
    let fetched = [];
    d3.csv(data).then(csv_file => {
        for (let c in csv_file) {
            fetched.push(csv_file[c]["Sentence"]);
            }
     })
     return fetched;
            }
```

And then this second function:

```
const parseData = async (data) => {
    let parsed = await fetchData(data);
    console.log(parsed)
    }
```

When I run `parseData(csv_file)` I see the array in the console, so all good. However, in my IDE I get this message telling me that the `await` keyword is of no use there.

The issue is, if I change my `parseData()` function to:

```
const parseData = async (data) => {
    let parsed = await fetchData(data);
    for (let p of parsed) {
        console.log(p)
        }
    }
```

... Norhing shows in the console! :O So basically, `console.log(parsed)` shows the array, but looping through it shows nothing. I'm suspecting that I haven't completely grasped how to return data from async / await functions.

What am I doing wrong here? I know I could do this loop in the first function, but I want to learn and understand how I can pass the result of the first function (the `parsed` array) onto the second one, and they loop through it.

I checked a few solutions before posting, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788603/passing-down-the-result-of-a-promise), but I'm still struggling.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: `fetchData` does not return anything

Comment: Thanks! Well that's a start! Should I place my `return` within a `.then()` chain?